# Chalkboard-alike wall for children

Tags: walls, paint

I was thinking about converting a wall in one of the rooms into an improvised chalkboard [similar to these](https://www.pinterest.com/explore/charcoal-walls/). The idea is to cover it with a charcoal-close interior paint.

It has to meet a few key criteria:

1. **Safe** for kids. Obviously. They are the primary users of the thing.
2. **Durable [mechanical wear]**, i.e. be thick and hard after it dried out; at least harder than chalk so that the active contact does not destroy the color/paint.
3. **"chalk friendly"** texture so that it's actually **usable** within the bounds of desired application.

The other criteria are more of nice to have, but way less important.

1. **Durable [water impact]**, i.e. splash-resistant at least to some degree. Kids and myself are known to be not super-precise in movements, water on the wall is expected once a season. It would be nice if such situation does not ruin the chalkboard instantly.
2. **Easy to find, replenish, and re-paint** -- I am not expecting even the most durable paint to last forever.

---

How do I find and "assess" such a paint [if it at all exists]? So far I found the one on the picture below, but I don't know about it much, nor about any other paints available on the US market.

---

P.S. I'm very open to criticism targeting my idea itself as well. You may add it to the answer, or post a comment under my question.

[image: paint]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having met a few attempts to use chalkboard paint (couldn't tell you the brand) I'd strongly suggest looking for a (used/surplus, assuming cost is a factor) chalkboard, it will work much better. Somewhere within 50 miles of you there is almost always a school being either remodeled or abandoned; or you can leave that part to an architectural salvage firm and buy from them (it will cost more.)

If using the paint, I would suggest applying it to a sheet of tempered hardboard (e.g. Masonite®) rather than directly to the wall surface.

Comment: I totally agree. +100 if I could. Do not attempt to use chalk board paint in any existing wall surface. This should be especially obvious in the case of sheet rock walls. Any existing walls were most assuredly painted with a roller and have a texture that would be next to unusable as a chalk surface.

Answer (score 2):

I've had good success using the Rustoleum brand Chalkboard paint.  I'm sure the brand you found would be similar.

In our kids room, we decided to make the bottom half of the wall a chalkboard.  Rather than trying to use the existing drywall, I cut and put up a sheet of 1/2" MDF and put trim above and below it.  The MDF was then primed, sanded, primed again, and then painted with the chalkboard paint following all the instructions (I think it took 2-3 coats).

It has survived years of them playing in the room and drawing and erasing.  My experience has been that the chalkboard paint is great as long as you use it on a hard, flat surface and follow all the instructions.